# shell script with curl and grep

Tags: curl

I  have an array of url's. I want to open them and if they are opening up without any error , show the status as running else not running. How can I achieve the desired output mentioned below, by removing all other messages from current output.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 urlArray=('http://url1:port1' 'http://url2:port2' 'http://url3:port3')
for url in "${urlArray[@]}"
 do 
   result=`curl $url | head -1`

    if (echo $result | grep '<?xml' >/dev/null 2>&1); then
        echo Running
    else
        echo Not Running
     fi
 done
```

**Current output of script is**

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12980    0 12980    0     0   711k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Running

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'url2:port2'
Not Running

curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'url3:port3'
Not Running
```

**Desired output:**

```
Running
Not Running
Not Running
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-s` flag suppresses output:

```
$ curl foo
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'foo'
$ curl -s foo
$
```

From the curl man page:

```
   -s/--silent
          Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute.
```

Answer (score 1):

add -S (upper) so you can still see errors:

from man:   -S/--show-error    Show error. With -s, make curl show errors when they occur